# Can setting MinHeight of a WPF control be a workaround for failing VirtualizingStackPanel.ExtendViewport?

Tags: wpf, xaml, ui-virtualization

And if it is, what control would be the best bet? DataGrid that has the virtualization or something else? This happens very very rarely so trial and error is not an option. Portion of my xaml and converter used is in the end.

This happens sometimes (maybe 1/1000?) when DataGrid's itemssource (ICollectionView) is refreshed.

> 2017-10-06 09:00:35: myapp.exe Error: 0 : Unhandled exception.
>   System.ArgumentException: Height must be non-negative.
>
> at System.Windows.Rect.set_Height(Double value)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.ExtendViewport(IHierarchicalVirtualizationAndScrollInfo
>   virtualizationInfoProvider, Boolean isHorizontal, Rect viewport,
>   VirtualizationCacheLength cacheLength, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit
>   cacheUnit, Size stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size
>   stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size
>   stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size
>   stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size stackPixelSize, Size
>   stackLogicalSize, Int32& itemsInExtendedViewportCount)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.IsExtendedViewportFull()
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.ShouldItemsChangeAffectLayoutCore(Boolean
>   areItemChangesLocal, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingPanel.OnItemsChangedInternal(Object
>   sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
>
> at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChanged(Object sender,
>   ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnItemAdded(Object
>   item, Int32 index)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnCollectionChanged(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
>
> at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender,
>   EventArgs args)
>
> at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>
> at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>
> at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32
>   index, T item)
>
> at MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal.Insert(Object item,
>   Object seed, IComparer comparer)
>
> at MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupRoot.AddToSubgroup(Object
>   item, LiveShapingItem lsi, CollectionViewGroupInternal group, Int32
>   level, Object name, Boolean loading)
>
> at MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupRoot.AddToSubgroups(Object
>   item, LiveShapingItem lsi, CollectionViewGroupInternal group, Int32
>   level, Boolean loading)
>
> at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.AddItemToGroups(Object
>   item, LiveShapingItem lsi)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   args, Int32 adjustedOldIndex, Int32 adjustedNewIndex)
>
> at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>
> at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32
>   index, T item)
>
> at
>   MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView.LoadSnapshotCore(IEnumerable
>   source)
>
> at
>   MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView.LoadSnapshot(IEnumerable
>   source)
>
> at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshInternal()

XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Name="SelectedObjectsRowDefinition">
            <RowDefinition.Height>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GridRowHeightConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="SelectedObjectsExpander" Path="IsExpanded" />
                    <Binding Path="IsSelectedObjectsVisible" />
                    <Binding ElementName="SelectedObjectsGrid" Path="Items.Count" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </RowDefinition.Height>
        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="SelectedSwitchesRowDefinition">
            <RowDefinition.Height>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GridRowHeightConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="SelectedSwitchesExpander" Path="IsExpanded" />
                    <Binding Path="IsSelectedSwitchesVisible" />
                    <Binding ElementName="SelectedSwitchesGrid" Path="Items.Count" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </RowDefinition.Height>
        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="SelectionsRowDefinition">
            <RowDefinition.Height>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GridRowHeightConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="SelectionsExpander" Path="IsExpanded" />
                    <Binding Path="IsSelectionSetsVisible" />
                    <Binding ElementName="SelectionSetsGrid" Path="Items.Count" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </RowDefinition.Height>
        </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander Grid.Row="0" Header="{DynamicResource XpStrSelectedObjects}" x:Name="SelectedObjectsExpander" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SelectedObjectsExp" 
              IsExpanded="{Binding IsSelectedObjectsExpanded}" Visibility="{Binding IsSelectedObjectsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid Margin="15,0,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Background="White"
                  Visibility="{Binding ShowSelectedObjectsInfoPanel, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="0,0,4,0">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,4,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedObjectsInfoPanelText}"
                               FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{StaticResource NisStrShowAnyway}" 
                            Visibility="{Binding IsFetchObjectsAnywayVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                            Command="{ui:CommandHandler FetchObjectsAnyway}" 
                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ShowAnywayBtn"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <DataGrid Name="SelectedObjectsGrid" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SelectedObjectsDgd"
                      Visibility="{Binding ShowSelectedObjectsInfoPanel, Converter={StaticResource BoolNegationToVisibilityConverter}}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedObjectItems}"
                      SelectionMode="Extended"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="0,0,4,0">
```

Convert-method of IMultivalueConverter used in XAML above:

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            bool isExpanded = (bool)values[0];
            bool isVisible = (bool)values[1];
            int itemsCount = (int)values[2];

            if (!isVisible || !isExpanded || itemsCount == 0)
                return System.Windows.GridLength.Auto;
            else
                return new System.Windows.GridLength(1, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Star);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new System.Windows.GridLength(1, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Star);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did setting min height fix the problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: @NeilB : Sorry, but can't remember. However the code still looks like that so I guess yes.

Comment: OK I set minheight, as well as a try catch when adding items to the collection. Hopefully that will take care of it.